# Is this sequence monotonically decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $a_n = \frac{p_n - p_{n-1}}{p_n \log p_n}$ where $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime.  Is this sequence decreasing (or decreasing after some $N$)?

Comment: Very unlikely. If $p_n- p_{n-1}$ is a small prime gap, there will often come a much larger gap after that. If there are infinitely many twin primes, $p_n - p_{n-1} = 2$ happens infinitely often, and then $a_{n+1} > a_n$.

Comment: I used ListPlot on mathematica to look at the graph of a_n from n = 2 to 700000 and it's really striking. It looks like there are a dozen (or more) bands of decreasing curves with an asymptote at the horizontal axis, concave up. The curves become more and more scattered along the top.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence is not decreasing.

You have for example:

$$a_4=\frac{2}{7 \cdot \log 7}=0,14 \dots$$
$$a_5=\frac{4}{11 \log 11}=0,15 \dots$$

Doing more examples,you will see that the sequence is getting in general smaller,but it is not monotone..

Here you can see a plot:

[image]

EDIT: Consider two twin primes,for example these ones: $3,5$ and $5,7$.

Then it will be like that:
$$a_n=\frac{5-3}{5 \cdot \log{5}}=\frac{2}{5 \cdot \log{5}}$$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{7-5}{7 \cdot \log{7}}=\frac{2}{7 \cdot \log{7}}$$

At this case, $a_{n}>a_{n+1}$.

So,you can't conclude that the sequence is decreasing,because then the relation $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ would stand $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you for the data evinda.  However, we still don't know if the sequence is eventually monotonic.

Comment: @MustafaSaid I edited my answer..

Comment: I am asking if there exists an $N$ such that $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ for all $n \geq N$.  NOT "for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$".  This is what I mean by "eventually monotonic."  I should have been more specific about this point.  Thanks evinda.